# Azure load Balancers and NSG rules to allow traffic through

Tags: azure-load-balancer, azure-nsg

What I'm trying to do is detailed below the diagram

[image]

The client can only connect to VM1 and VM2 through the standard Azure load balancer on port X, and not directly to the VM IP addresses

We have a rule in the LB to pass traffic on port X to the backend pool, which consist of VM1 and VM2

Sticky Sessions are set to Client IP

There is no health probe for this rule

Windows Firewalls on VM's are deactivated

NSG Rules Setup so far tried

**Scenario1**

```
netcat exposing port X on VM1 and VM2
NSG rule allowing traffic from Client IP to Load Balancer IP
DENY all inbound

From Client
telnet 10.100.23.4 X - Connection Failed
telnet 10.100.23.5 X - Connection Failed
telnet 10.100.23.6 X - Connection Failed
```

**Scenario2**

```
netcat exposing port X on VM1 and VM2
NSG rule allowing traffic from Client IP to Load Balancer IP on port X
NSG rule allowing traffic from Internal LB IP to entire subnet on all ports
DENY all inbound

From Client
telnet 10.100.23.4 X - Connection Failed
telnet 10.100.23.5 X - Connection Failed
telnet 10.100.23.6 X - Connection Failed
```

**Scenario3**

```
netcat exposing port X on VM1 and VM2
NSG rule allowing traffic from Client IP to Load Balancer IP on port X
NSG rule allowing traffic from Internal LB IP to entire subnet on all ports
NSG rule allowing traffic from Client IP to VM1 and VM2 IP
DENY all inbound

From Client
telnet 10.100.23.4 X - Connection Succeeded
telnet 10.100.23.5 X - Connection Succeeded
telnet 10.100.23.6 X - Connection Succeeded
```

Does anyone know of a combination of NSG rules I can use to deny direct access to VM1 and VM2 from the client, whilst allowing traffic to pass through the LB to the VM's?

I feel like I'm missing a trick here as this seems a pretty standard thing to do security wise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is about Internal Loadbalancer.
Since these are defined for loadbalancing within the VNET, we need to recall that routing within vnet is allowed by default.

Explicit Deny traffic from Client IP to Vm1 and VM2 is the only rule that should be required for the above scenario, can you please check?

Regards.
Aditya

Comment: Hi Aditya. Sorry, I'm not following. The traffic will not route through the load balancer to the VM, until I specifically add a rule allowing the traffic to get at the VM.  There's already a DENY all inbound rule after the allows.  Could you write out your suggested Rule list?